# Casting dinamico

Tags: c#, casting

En una aplicación de gestión, con una relación entre documentos (formulariosa), por ejemplo: pedido/albarán, debo poder navegar entre ellos, es decir desde un pedido abrir su albarán y viceversa.

```
frmPedido loPedido = (frmPedido)Application.OpenForms["frmPedido"];
if (!(loOrden is null))
{
    loPedido.BringToFront();

}
```

Lo que quiero es envolver este código en una función para aprovecharlo en cualquier formulario, pero para ello debo poder hacer un cast sin saber el tipo que me llega a la función.
Hay alguna manera de hacer un cast a partir del GetType() ?
Algo así:(pero que funcione claro està)

```
public static void SwapForm(Form tipoForm)
{
    Form formToOpen = new Form();
    (tipoForm.GetType)formToOpen = (tipoForm.GetType)Application.OpenForms["tipoForm.GetType"];
    if (!(formToOpen is null))
    {
        formToOpen.BringToFront();

    }
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respecto a la duda que planteas

En el que la implementación del método `SwapForm` no necesita conocer con que formulario concreto estás tratando para realizar llamadas métodos definidos en su interfaz de clase (como `BringToFront`) y por tanto un casting a `Form` que es la clase base de los formularios serviría:

```
public static void SwapForm(Form tipoForm)
{
    Form formToOpen = (Form)Application.OpenForms[tipoForm.Name];
    if (formToOpen != null)
    {
        formToOpen.BringToFront();

    }
}
```

En el caso de que necesitases hacer alguna operación adicional con el formulario que has intercambiado, y esta dependiera del tipo final del formulario esa lógica estaría mejor ubicada fuera de la función común e implementaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public static TFormType SwapForm<TFormType>(Form tipoForm) where TFormType : Form
{
    TFormType formToOpen = (TFormType)Application.OpenForms[tipoForm.Name];
    if (formToOpen != null)
    {
        formToOpen.BringToFront();
    }
    return formToOpen;
}
```

De esta forma el código que llama a la función de intercambiar podría interactuar con el tipo de formulario de destino.

Nota: en ambas implementaciones he modificado el uso de `Application.OpenForms` para consultar en base del nombre del formulario que es lo que se almacena como clave en base a la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0

Un saludo!